# Estimating species population from one sample, with confidence?

Tags: estimation, sampling

I subscribe to a sample of real-time data from a vendor. Once per second, the vendor delivers (a) a random sample of records for the given second, and (b) the total number of records the vendor processed during that second, from which my sample was drawn. So for a given second, the vendor might deliver (a) 100 records, and (b) that 1,740 total records were processed in that second.

Let's imagine each record is a colored ball, with each unique color being a "species." Each ball has exactly one color. Imagine that in one second, I received 100 balls, of which 7 were red, and that there were 1,740 total balls processed in that second. How can I estimate how many of the 1,740 total balls processed that second were of the "red" species?

Of course, I know that 7 of 100 = 7% of my sample are red, so I can estimate 7% of 1,740 = 121.8 ≈ 122 balls are red in the total records. While that may be the most likely estimate, it gives me no sense for how confident I should be in that estimate.

Using the data I have available, how can I get an estimate for population count with a confidence interval?

Comment: What you are looking for is a [Binomial proportion confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval)

Comment: Convenient if you use R, is Jeffreys' 95% CI. If you have 7 Successes in 100 trials than 95% CI for success probability $p$ is $( 0.032,\, 0.040).$ in R use code `
`qbeta(c(.025,.075), 7.5, 93.5)` to get
$0.03185496, 0.04036367.$ Otherwise, I suggest Agresti-Coull 95% CI. $( 0.033, 0.143),$ which is easier on a hand calculator. Link in previous comment discusses several other possibilities.

Comment: This is great feedback! Does it matter if there are many different colors of balls? I typically think of binomial techniques when a trial has two categorical outcomes (success vs failure), as opposed to many (red, green, blue, orange, etc.)